# How to properly create and use makefile

Tags: c, shell, makefile

I'm getting started with makefiles and I'm having some problems.

I have one file which is `fase_1.c` that I want to compile and run.

I'm trying to make a simple makefile where I `make` and `make clean`.
This is what I tried:

```
OBJECTS = fase_1.o
CFLAGS = -Wall
NAME = makefile

build: $(OBJECTS)
    cc $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(NAME)

clean: 
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(NAME)
```

I do `make`, and it creates `fase_1.o` and `makefile`. Then I run `./makefile` (is there another way to do it without like make or make clean but to run it?). Then I type `make clean`, and it says that there's a missing separator and that the line is ignored and doesn't remove `fase_1.o` and `makefile` (what I want to do). Am I separating the lines right? Maybe it has something to do with tab or my editing but I can't find where.

Comment: Never "run" `./makefile`, it's not a script, and can't be understood by a shell. You need to type `make` or `make clean` as appropriate. Also, instead of `build: $(OBJECTS)` write `$(NAME) : $(OBJECTS)`. Instead of `NAME = makefile` write something like `NAME = fase`, or whatever you want as the name of the object file.

Comment: is the clean alright? Because that's what was failing. How do it run my program appropiately using a makefile? I get that "make" creates fase_1.o and the makefile executable, am I wrong? Then I have to run makefile, but what is the way to do that without ./? I didn't understand what you meant @blippy

Comment: `clean` is fine, ostensibly. You may have messed up the tabbing, which might be the cause. It's impossible to tell here. Run `grep -P '^t' makefile`, which will print all the lines beginning with a tab. You should see the `rm` lines output. If not, then that's likely to be the problem: spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: The way you make use of the makefile is to run the command `make -f makefile`, or `make -f makefile clean`, as an answer already suggested. A better solution is to call the file `Makefile` rather than `makefile`, and then just do `make` or `make clean`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a rewrite. Call it `Makefile`, though, not `makefile`:

```
OBJECTS = fase_1.o
CFLAGS = -Wall
NAME = fase

$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    cc $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(NAME)

run : $(NAME)
    ./fase

.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(NAME)
```

There are fancier improvements that could be made, but it's probably best not to get bogged down at this stage. As a bonus, I have added `.PHONY`. This tells `make` that the target `clean` is a phony target; it doesn't actually create anything called `clean`.

You don't have to make `run` dependent on `$(NAME)`, of course, but it makes sense in this particular context.

Comment: thanks a lot ! It makes and cleans now. However, is there any way to do something like clean but to run ./fase? Something like make run? @blippy

Comment: @Januan Yes. It's no different in principle than `clean`. I have amended the original `Makefile` to take account of this (I can't do it in the comment section).

Comment: @Januan No problem. Remember, `clean` is not an in-built rule, it is something you created. So, just as you made up the rule `clean`, you can make up other rules, too. If I was going to be consistent, I could make `run` a `.PHONY` target.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using GNU make. From the info page:

> By default, when 'make' looks for the makefile, it tries the following
>   names, in order: 'GNUmakefile', 'makefile' and 'Makefile'.

Your executable is called `makefile`. When you run `make`, it tries to parse the executable as Makefile. Either rename the executable, or specify the makefile explicitly:

```
make -f Makefile clean
```